# Does ftrace allow capture of system call arguments to the Linux kernel, or only function names?

Tags: linux-kernel, trace, ftrace

The goal is to examine arguments passed to specific system calls (e.g. exec, open, etc.) by any process.

From the [official documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt), no capability to log function arguments is described (looked mostly at the "function" tracer, as I don't need the graph).

I wanted to make sure I'm not overlooking something and wasting time using something more exotic if I could actually do this within the framework of ftrace.

Comment: If you're only looking for system calls from user space, plus their arguments, then you want the simple userland utility `strace`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have limited experience with `ftrace`, although I have used it for for function stack traces and latency issues. (People with more experience can possibly suggest) Its pretty much the same experience using `trace-cmd` and `kernelshark`.

However, if you want to trace syscalls, function params, kernel APIs and return values etc. within the kernel space a better choice would be to go with `systemtap`. It has an extensive list of [Samples & Doc](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/) which is good for function call tracing, argument values passed etc. You may want to look at some samples and taylor them to your requirement. See `general/para-callgraph-verbose.stp` and `process/sleeptime.stp`

"

**general/para-callgraph-verbose.stp** - Callgraph Tracing with Verbose Arguments
keywords: TRACE CALLGRAPH

Print a timed per-thread microsecond-timed callgraph, complete with pretty-printed function parameters and return values. The first parameter names the function probe points to trace. The optional second parameter names the probe points for trigger functions, which acts to enable tracing for only those functions that occur while the current thread is nested within the trigger.

```
stap para-callgraph-verbose.stp 'kernel.function("*@fs/proc*.c")' \
'kernel.function("vfs_read")' -c "cat /proc/sys/vm/* || true"
```

**process/strace.stp** - Trace system calls
keywords: _BEST PROCESS SYSCALL

The script loosely emulates strace, when applied to individual processes or hierarchies (via -c/-x), or the entire system (without -c/-x). A few output configuration parameters may be set with -G.

```
stap strace.stp -c "sleep 1"
```

"

Note you will need to install the correct version of the `debug kernel` and `kernel-devel` rpms/deb for `stap` to work correctly. For this just use `stap-prep` and install the dependencies shown depending on the flavour you are on.

Comment: Tracing system calls is made simpler with: https://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/#process/strace.stp - no kernel debug symbols required e.g.

Comment: @fche thanks for the update. strace.stp was not available with my version of systemtap-examples. I will update the thread.

Comment: (often samples included in later versions of stap do run fine on earlier ones.)

Answer (score 0):

Give "STRACE" a shot. It monitors the interaction betn userspace and kernel.

A sample output can be found here :
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/11/strace-examples/

Alternatively,  Since you are saying specific system calls, i am assuming you are interested in only a couple of them.

If you have to use FTRACE alone, you can add your own trace event in the relevant header files in include/trace/events/.h, using TRACE_EVENT macro and call this new trace function during the sytem call handler inside the kernel.

Of course, this requires some code modification, but should be easy enough to get you going quickly.

Comment: Downvoted because strace looks at one specific process, while I'm looking for a tool that looks at all processes on the system.